# Как при помощи python войти внутрь Docker контейнера и выполнять там команды?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, subprocess

Изначально я пытался зайти внутрь Docker контейнера и исполнять там команды при помощи библиотеки `subprocess`:

```
 def enter_container(container):
        command = f'docker exec -i -d {container} bash'
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
        subprocess.call('ls', shell=True)  # Проверка работоспособности
```

Но получал вот такую ошибку:

```
"ls" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
```

Компилирую файл:

```
def compile_file(compile_command):
    print('Compiling command:', compile_command)
    subprocess.call(compile_command, shell=True)
```

Ошибка:

```
"g++" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
```

Запускаю файл:

```
def run_file(exec_command: str, stdin: Optional[str] = None):
    print('Execution command:', exec_command)

    start_time = time.time()
    result = subprocess.run(exec_command,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            shell=True,
                            text=True,
                            input=stdin)

    runtime = time.time() - start_time

    return {'output': result.stdout,
            'runtime': runtime,
            'error': result.stderr}
```

Результат:

```
{'output': '', 
'runtime': 0.012002706527709961, 
'error': '"." \xadҐ пў«пҐвбп ў\xadгваҐ\xad\xadҐ© Ё«Ё ў\xadҐи\xadҐ©\nЄ®¬\xa0\xad¤®©,ЁбЇ®«\xadпҐ¬®© Їа®Ја\xa0¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї\xa0ЄҐв\xadл¬ д\xa0©«®¬.\n'}
```

Текст ошибки - что-то связанное с **"не является внутренней или внешней командой"**

Как правильно запускать команды внутри контейнера при помощи pyhton?

**EDIT1:**
Из команды для входа внутрь контейнера я убрал флаг **-d**, теперь по идее туда можно отправлять какие-нибудь команды, но теперь код просто ожидает именно моего ввода, т.е. он просто не идет дальше

Comment: `docker exec -i -d {container} ls` или `docker exec -i -d {container} bash -c 'ls'`

Comment: @TotalPusher до этого я так и делал, но это занимало слишком много времени (на Windows), и мне подсказали, что можно сначала войти внутрь контейнера, а потом прямо там исполнять нужные мне команды, так что я пытаюсь реализовать именно этот способ.

Comment: попробуй зайти через `bash --login`

Comment: Ну последняя ошибка да: **"." не является внутренней или внешней
командой,исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом**.